# bootstrap 3 sidebar de-activing subitems

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a sidebar navigation that doesn't collapse and changes a tab area to the right. I have provided a link to jsfiddle which is what I currently have, the problem is that the parent item doesn't deactivate when you click on a child, and if you click on a parent item it actives all the children items. This behavior prevents the reactivation of the parent item until a different 2nd parent item is selected. however even when you do this one of the children items of the 1st parent is still activated.

Anyone know how to make it so that selecting a child node doesn't activate the parent node, or how to deactivate all other nodes when a node is clicked? That would be awesome, thanks!

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyp19nd5/)

Html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <nav class="nav-sidebar">
                <ul class="nav tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab_airConditioning" data-toggle="tab">Air Conditioning</a>
                        <ul class="nav sub-nav tabs">
                            <li class=""><a href="#tab_Installation" data-toggle="tab">Installation</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#tab_Maintenance" data-toggle="tab">Maintenance</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#tab_Repair" data-toggle="tab">Repair</a></li>                               
                        </ul>
                    </li>                       

                    <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Heating</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Controls</a></li>                               
                </ul>
            </nav>              
        </div>
            <!-- tab content -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active text-style" id="tab_airConditioning">
                <h2>Air Conditioning</h2>
                <p>
                Random text for Air Conditioning dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" class="img-rounded pull-right">   
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane text-style" id="tab_Installation">
                <h2>Installation</h2>
                <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x90" class="img-rounded pull-left">
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane text-style" id="tab_Maintenance">
                <h2>Maintenance</h2>
                <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-rounded pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane text-style" id="tab_Repair">
                <h2>Repair</h2>
                <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-rounded pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane text-style" id="tab2">
                <h2>Heating</h2>
                <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-rounded pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane text-style" id="tab3">
                <h2>Controls</h2>
                <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum 
                </p>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-rounded pull-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-sidebar { 
width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0; 
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
 .nav-sidebar a {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.08s linear;
    transition: all 0.08s linear;
 }
 .nav-sidebar .active a { 
     cursor: default;
     background-color: #0b56a8; 
     color: #fff; 
 }
 .nav-sidebar .active a:hover {
     background-color: #E50000;   
 }
 .nav-sidebar .text-overflow a,
 .nav-sidebar .text-overflow .media-body {
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
     text-overflow: ellipsis; 
 }
 .nav-sidebar .sub-nav a {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
 }
```

Comment: My issue now is that when you select a child node, after first selecting it's parent node, the parent node becomes unclickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current CSS:

```
 .nav-sidebar .active a { 
     cursor: default;
     background-color: #0b56a8; 
     color: #fff; 
 }
 .nav-sidebar .active a:hover {
     background-color: #E50000;   
 }
```

Gives all children under the li.active a the styles, but when you want to be more specific and you only want that particular link (a) to have that style, you would use the immediate child selector > :

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/child-selector-css-selector/

```
 .nav-sidebar .active > a { 
     cursor: default;
     background-color: #0b56a8; 
     color: #fff; 
 }
 .nav-sidebar .active > a:hover {
     background-color: #E50000;   
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hyp19nd5/1/

Comment: Thanks! your solution solved half of my problem, now I just need to figure out how to make it so only one item is active at a time and I am golden!

Comment: My issue now is that when you select a child node, after first selecting it's parent node, the parent node becomes unclickable.